# How to create a project template for Ruby on Rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I build Rails applications I find myself doing the same things over and over again.  This includes adding the same gems/plugins, configuration info and custom initializers, rake tasks etc... etc....

This can't be a good thing.

So, is there a way to package all this repetitive code into some sort of project template ... so that I can do a "rails myapp" and have everything good to go from there?

Btw, running 2.3.5 if that matters :)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[App templates is probably the feature you are looking for](http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3).

Answer (score 2):

Many people just create the "template" and then commit it to a repository, possibly on GitHub, for easy access later. I personally find that this works really well.